# Does anybody know of some data visualization packages for the Linux command line/terminal?

Tags: linux, data-visualization, bash, unix

I am new to Linux and am also beginning to learn data science. I am playing around with Termgraph which is a package used with Python to visualize very simple bar charts in the command line. I am wondering if anyone has come across any other packages or techniques to visualize data in the command line? I really like the thought of being very close to the files I am working with in the command line and doing very quick preliminary testing/visualizing of data/data sets in the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want [visidata](https://www.visidata.org/).

> VisiData is an interactive multitool for tabular data. It combines the clarity of a spreadsheet, the efficiency of the terminal, and the power of Python, into a lightweight utility which can handle millions of rows with ease.

Comment: Just what I've been looking for! Thanks!